# Slope of a production function

Tags: macroeconomics, production-function

Let $F(K,L)$ be a production function with variables $K$ for capital and $L$ for labor.

The slope of the $F(\overline K,L)$ ($K$ taken constant) is defined as the marginal product of labor ($MPL$) such that:

$$MPL=F(K,L+1)-F(K,L)$$

Most production functions have a positive decreasing slope due to diminishing marginal product and therefore are not straight lines. How is the $MPL$ formula still valid? Isn't that the same formula to find a gradient $m$ of a line (i.e. $\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x{1}}$)? If we take any function whose representation isn't a line, its slope at a certain point is equal to the slope of the tangent at the point and not the formula for the gradient $m$.

Also, supposing the given formula for $MPL$ is true, shouldn't we also have $MPL=\frac{\partial F}{\partial L}$?

Comment: So where did you get that initial MPL formula? That would work if we are in discrete scenario with no $\Delta$. You are right that the MPL is the partial derivative.

Comment: @VCG, it's written in my intermediate macroeconomics book. Alright so basically the $L+1$ indicates that we are working in a discrete scenario. And in a continuous one, my last line would hold true?

Comment: You should check the exact context in the book, but I think they are dealing with discrete. Because the formula you gave is the difference quotient, the discrete equivalent to derivative : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: @VCG, thanks for the link. It's weird because they draw a production function graph (positive decreasing slope) and label its slope at different points as $MPL$. Isn't drawing a graph implying a continuous scenario? If so, shouldn't I refuse that the slope be $F(K,L+1)-F(K,L)$?

Comment: Well if the class is in a discrete context, they probably draw the curve smooth for convenience/display.

Comment: I'm not sure about that refuse slope part - if it's in the context of a HW problem or something, then doing what the book wants is likely the correct approach.

Comment: @Sadem you're right though. the graph of the production function $\mathbb{N}_+ \times \mathbb{N}_+ \ni (K,L) \mapsto F(K,L)$ should rather consinst of points $\{(K_i, L_j, F_{ij}) : i,j = 0,1,\ldots\}$ than a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (partial) derivative of a continuous function is defined as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F(\overline K, L)}{\partial L} := \lim_{\Delta L \to 0}\frac{F(\overline K, L + \Delta L) - F(\overline K, L)}{\Delta L}.
\end{align}
Now if $L \in \mathbb{N}$, then you have a lower bound for the increment $\mathbb{N} \ni \Delta L \geq 1$. Otherwise the definition above is not well defined for $\Delta L = 0$.
Such that we finally arrive at the approximation
 \begin{align}
\frac{\partial F(\overline K, L)}{\partial L} \approx \frac{F(\overline K, L + 1) - F(\overline K, L)}{1}.
\end{align}